# programmatically obtain a list of android devices connected to adb

Tags: android, adb

Is there any way to programmatically obtain a list of android devices connected to adb ?

I want to do it in Java on a desktop application. I have the path of adb.exe but a parsing on the "adb devices" response doesn't seems to be the best idea.

Is there a more reliable method ?

Comment: Why is parsing on the "adb devices" response not the best idea? What can be more reliable to obtain ADB devices than asking ADB itself?

Comment: [pyadb is a python library](https://github.com/sch3m4/pyadb) that allows you to interact with adb programmatically. This API defines a get_devices() method which returns a list of device objects. From their code it seems like they are calling `adb devices` and parsing the resulting output into the list of objects. I would guess this is the easiest route to take with java too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optimal solution depends on what you are going to do with the list. If you are going to run some adb commands on the devices you find - parsing `adb devices` output is the obvious choice. Another option would be going through the USB stack and collecting serial numbers of devices with ADB interface enumerated. Or my favorite one - under Linux I just create a custom  `udev` rule which keeps track of all connected ADB devices. Mine is using a database, but it could be as simple as creating a symlink for every ADB device and then checking the file list.

Answer (score 6):

this is the how I done it

```
try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb devices");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));  
        String line = null;  

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+)(\\s+)(device)");
        Matcher matcher;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
            if (line.matches(pattern.pattern())) {
                matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                if (matcher.find())
                    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I get error when I execute the above code - java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified; Though I am running it from adb directory.

Comment: instead of .exec("adb devices"); 
try to add the path of your adb executable 


.exec("C:/androidSDK//....adb.exe devices");

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a Kotlin solution, I've adapted Buda Florin's answer:

```kotlin
class Cli {
    fun runCommand(cmd: String, workingDir: File = File("."), timeout: Duration = 3.minutes): String? {
        // this is modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441962/940217
        return try {
            val parts = "\\s".toRegex().split(cmd)
            val proc = ProcessBuilder(*parts.toTypedArray())
                .directory(workingDir)
                .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
                .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
                .start()

            proc.waitFor(timeout.inWholeSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            proc.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
}

class AdbUtils(){
    fun listDevices(): List<String>? {
        val c = Cli()
        val adbDevicesResponse :String? = c.runCommand("adb devices")
        var deviceIds = adbDevicesResponse?.lines()?.mapNotNull {
            val matches = """^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\s+)(device)""".toRegex().find(it)
            matches?.groupValues?.get(1)
        }
        return deviceIds
    }
}
```