# error when import kotlin project android studio 3.5.3

Tags: kotlin, import

I try to import project
i get this error when import project in android studio 3.5.3

**Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**

and this error

**This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.6 or newer**

```
    import org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441962
fun String.runCommand(
    workingDir: File = File("."),
    timeoutAmount: Long = 60,
    timeoutUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS
): String? = try {
    ProcessBuilder("\\s".toRegex().split(this))
        .directory(workingDir)
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .start().apply { waitFor(timeoutAmount, timeoutUnit) }
        .inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
} catch (e: java.io.IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    null
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    buildToolsVersion("29.0.2")
    viewBinding.isEnabled = true

    val gitVersion = listOf(
        "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD",
        "git rev-list HEAD --count",
        "git rev-parse --short HEAD"
    ).joinToString("-") { it.runCommand()?.trim() ?: "" } +
            (if (("git status -s".runCommand() ?: "").isBlank()) "" else "-dirty")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.test.cale"
        minSdkVersion(15)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 621
        versionName = "6.2.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resConfigs("en", "fa", "ckb", "ar", "ur", "ps", "glk", "azb", "ja")
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "PersianCalendar-$versionName-$gitVersion")
    }

    signingConfigs {
        create("nightly") {
            storeFile = rootProject.file("nightly.keystore")
            storePassword = "android"
            keyAlias = "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword = "android"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        create("nightly") {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("nightly")
            versionNameSuffix = "-${defaultConfig.versionName}-$gitVersion-nightly"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".nightly"
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            versionNameSuffix = "-${defaultConfig.versionName}-$gitVersion"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        }
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            // Maybe proguard-android-optimize.txt in future
            // setProguardFiles(listOf(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"))
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":equinox"))

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION}")

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-rc02")
    implementation("com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:2.0.0")

    val navVersion = "2.1.0"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navVersion")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navVersion")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0")

    implementation("androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0")

    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.2.0")

    // debugImplementation("com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-alpha-2")
    // debugImplementation("com.github.pedrovgs:lynx:1.1.0")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.2.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:rules:1.2.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0")
}
```

please resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Top-level Project Gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-rc01")
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "1.3.61"))
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven("https://jitpack.io")
    }
}

task("clean") {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```