# Class example is not abstract and does not implement fun writeToParcel() defined in android.os.Parcelable

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

In my Android project, I want to add a Bundle including a Place object described below to my Intent. Since serializable was slow and not recommended, I preferred Parcelable.

Although **I use Kotlin 1.3.72**, I have problems paralyzing some data classes. Example:-

```
import kotlinx.android.parcel.IgnoredOnParcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class QariItem(
  val id: Int,
  val name: String,
  val url: String,
  val path: String,
  val db: String? = null
) : Parcelable {
  @IgnoredOnParcel
  val databaseName = if (db.isNullOrEmpty()) null else db

  val isGapless: Boolean
    get() = databaseName != null
}
```

## bulid.gradle.kt

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile


plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("kapt")


}



// https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441962
fun String.runCommand(
    workingDir: File = File("."),
    timeoutAmount: Long = 60,
    timeoutUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS
): String? = try {
    ProcessBuilder("\\s".toRegex().split(this))
        .directory(workingDir)
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .start().apply { waitFor(timeoutAmount, timeoutUnit) }
        .inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
} catch (e: java.io.IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    null
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    buildToolsVersion("29.0.3")

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    val gitVersion = listOf(
        "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD",
        "git rev-list HEAD --count",
        "git rev-parse --short HEAD"
    ).joinToString("-") { it.runCommand()?.trim() ?: "" } +
            (if (("git status -s".runCommand() ?: "").isBlank()) "" else "-dirty")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "ye.ansarallah.Almumin"
        minSdkVersion(15)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 623
        versionName = "3.1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        resConfigs("en", "fa", "ckb", "ar", "ur", "ps", "glk", "azb", "ja")
//        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "PersianCalendar-$versionName-$gitVersion")
        multiDexEnabled = false
    }

    signingConfigs {
        create("nightly") {
            storeFile = rootProject.file("nightly.keystore")
            storePassword = "android"
            keyAlias = "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword = "android"
        }
    }



    buildTypes {
        create("nightly") {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("nightly")
//            versionNameSuffix = "-${defaultConfig.versionName}-$gitVersion-nightly"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".nightly"
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
        }

        getByName("debug") {
//            versionNameSuffix = "-${defaultConfig.versionName}-$gitVersion"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        }

        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}



dependencies {

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.72")

    implementation("com.github.persian-calendar:equinox:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.github.persian-calendar:calendar:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.github.persian-calendar:praytimes:1.0.0")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION}")

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3")
    implementation("androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:2.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0")

    val navVersion = "2.2.2"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navVersion")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navVersion")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0")

    implementation("androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0")

    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.4")

    //weather implamentation

    implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:2.0.0")
    implementation("com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0")

    // debugImplementation("com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-alpha-2")
    // debugImplementation("com.github.pedrovgs:lynx:1.1.0")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.2.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:rules:1.2.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0")

    implementation("com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4")


    //Quran_Quarn


    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.6")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.6")

    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.7.2")

    implementation("androidx.media:media:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1")

    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")

    // rx
    implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19")
    implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1")

    // dagger
    api("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.27")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.27")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.26")


    // workmanager
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.4")

    implementation("com.squareup.okio:okio:2.6.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+")

    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2")
    kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2")

    implementation("com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1")
    debugImplementation("com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.3")
    testImplementation("com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3")
    testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.12.+")
    testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-dnsoverhttps:3.12.+")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0")
    implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1")



    implementation ("dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.9")
    implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-dnsoverhttps:3.12.+")


}
```

I really appreciate your help.[image]