# Java/Kotlin way to redirect command output to both stdout and String

Tags: java, kotlin, process

I am translating code from a NodeJS server to a Kotlin Ktor server.

The NodeJS code splits the output between a String to be handled by code, and realtime server logging :

```
const shellScript = exec("./myScript.sh",
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   // this happens when the script ends
   // stdout and stderr contain full script output
    if (error === null) {
      ...
    }
  });

// Realtime server logging
shellScript.stdout.on('data', (data) => { console.log(data); });
shellScript.stderr.on('data', (data) => { console.error(data); });
```

According to my understanding of `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`, we would need to spawn a thread (or a coroutine) to poll inputStream and errorStream in a loop and accumulate them in a volatile field.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: This may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421699/how-to-invoke-external-command-from-within-kotlin-code/41495542

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I had already checked that thread. According to my understanding and tests, all these answers give the logs only at the process end, which is not very good for long-running tasks.

Comment: Oh, OK. Do you know if your long running tasks flush regularly?

Comment: Yes they do. By the way, I have implemented the above with ProcessBuilder and a coroutine; much more bulky than the original JavaScript code, but at least it works. I'll post it as an answer if nothing cleaner comes up in the next few days...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the ProcessBuilder solution, which I initially wanted to avoid. It does the job though it is bulky. Let me know if a better API is made available!

```
var logs:String = ""
runCatching {
    var command:List<String> = listOf("command", "arg")
    parameters.params?.let {command += it} // dynamic args
    ProcessBuilder(command)
        .directory(File(scriptRoot))
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectErrorStream(true) // Merges stderr into stdout
        .start().also { process -> 
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // More info on this context switching : https://elizarov.medium.com/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761
                launch {
                    process.inputStream.bufferedReader().run {
                        while (true) { // Breaks when readLine returns null
                            readLine()?.let { line ->
                                logger.trace(line) // realtime logging
                                logs += "$line\n" // record
                            } ?: break
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                process.waitFor(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                if(process.isAlive) {
                    logs += "TIMEOUT occurred".also { logger.warn(it) } + "\n"
                    process.destroy()
                }
            }
        }
}.onSuccess { process ->
    if(process.exitValue() == 0) {
        // completed with success
    } else {
        // completed with failure
    }
    
}.onFailure { ex ->
    logs = ex.stackTraceToString()
}

// Logs are available in $logs
```