# How do I get the wlan0 inet address from kotlin android code?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get the wlan0 inet address through code in Kotlin for my android app. I have tried using `WifiManager.connectionInfo.ipAddress`, however that returned on both wifi and hotspot. However, if I run `ifconfig` in termux, an IP exists. I also tried using `InetAddress` class but that doesn't seem to have anything that works for my purpose.

I tried the solutions in this post: [How to invoke external command from within Kotlin code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421699/how-to-invoke-external-command-from-within-kotlin-code/41495542). Again, these returned nothing when passing in `ifconfig`.

Comment: Is it really ifconfig or is it "ipconfig"?

Comment: @Corni `ifconfig` is correct

Comment: Okay.. Sorry, but that was the only thing that came to my mind since I am not very familiar with Kotlin 

Answer (score 0):

You need to go though the available interfaces and look for wlan0

```
    val interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
    val list = interfaces.toList()
    //go through the available interfaces
    for (interface in list) {
        if (interface.name.equals("wlan0")) {
            //look into the interface's ipaddresses (ipv4,ipv6)
            interface.inetAddresses.toList().get(0).hostAddress
        }
    }
```